# Sockets - sending more data after reciving answer from server

Tags: windows, winapi, sockets, winsock

I have a client/server application.
The client sends a question to the server and receives an answer.

This works great - but when I'm trying to use the same socket again to send another question (without closing the socket - after receiving an answer) the server doesn't get the second question.

Here's the code for sending and receiving answer (this should work in a loop of some-sort):

```
char* buf = "GET /count.htm HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:666\r\nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml\r\nAccept-Language: en-us\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n";

int nBytesToSend= strlen(buf);
int iPos=0;

while(nBytesToSend)
{
    int nSent=send(hClientSocket,buf,nBytesToSend,0);
    assert(nSent!=SOCKET_ERROR);

    nBytesToSend-=nSent;
    iPos+=nSent;
}

//prepare buffer for incoming data
char serverBuff[256];
int nLeft=sizeof(serverBuff);
iPos=0;

do //loop till there are no more data
{
    int nNumBytes=recv(hClientSocket,serverBuff+iPos,nLeft,0);

    //check if cleint closed connection
    if(!nNumBytes)
        break;

    assert(nNumBytes!=SOCKET_ERROR);

    //update free space and pointer to next byte
    nLeft-=nNumBytes;
    iPos+=nNumBytes;

}while(1);
```

Comment: Do you get any error on the client side? Try adding `Connection: Keep-Alive` to your headers (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

Comment: The assertion inside the receiving loop fails (because it doesn't get a response from the server -> because the server doesn't send an answer -> because it doesn't get the second question from the client)

Comment: Figure out what's the error. IIRC on Windows it's `GetLastError()`. Also, the response might be shorter or larger then 256 bytes, how do you handle that?

Comment: The error is the client getting nothing from the server. assert(nNumBytes!=SOCKET_ERROR); failes

Comment: That could be for a number of reasons. There's a specific error code returned by `GetLastError()` that you would then pass to `FormatMessage()` or just lookup here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx. That would tell you what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Continuation of [Get response from server using the same socket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170973/get-response-from-server-using-the-same-socket)

Answer (score 0):

With this code it is impossible that you can ever *send* the second question, as you can never get out off the loop that reads the reply (except when you get a segmentation violation because your offset overflows the buffer, or when the peer closes the connection, in which case you can't send and he can't receive either).

And just asserting the absence of an error is never adequate. If you get an error you need to see what was and react accordingly. At the least you need to print it.